# Change size of an AE encrypted text column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, tablecolumn, always-encrypted

I have a table which uses Always Encrypted on SQL Server 2016. This varchar column initially had a field size of 50, which I want to reduce to 20. When I do that on SQL Server Management, I get the following error:

```
Explicit conversion from data type varchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'ColumnEncryptionKey', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDB') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' to varchar(20) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'ColumnEncryptionKey', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDB') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' is not allowed.
```

On my SSDT project, it gives slightly a different message, but it's the same error.

Basically, I'm not allowed to change the size. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

NOTE: The table I'm doing this schema change on, has no data in this particular column.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the size now?

Comment: We realized that the field doesn't need 50 characters, after a slight requirement change.

Comment: "The table I'm doing this schema change on, has no data in this particular column." - so have you tried removing the column entirely and separately adding it back on at the new size?

Comment: Yes, that works. But I'm doing this through the SSDT package so I directly did the schema change and let SSDT handle that but it fails.

Comment: @devC, It seems like SSDT does not support ALTER Column changes for column with encypted keys. I would suggest you to make this as part of your post deployment script. Please mention the error you are getting in SSDT

Comment: @VenkataramanR: SR0109: Microsoft.Rules.Data.DeploymentValidation: Operation Blocked: Type Conversion on encrypted column [dbo].[Orders].[ContactNo] is not allowed.